# How to access last n parameters in an AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I am receiving sensory data on AWS IoT and passing these values to a Lambda function using a rule. In the Lambda function which is coded in Python, I need to make a calculation based on the latest n values.

What is the best way of accessing previous parameters?

Answer (score 5):

Each Lambda invocation is supposed to be state-less and not aware of previous invocations (there's container reuse but you cannot rely on that).

If you need those, then you have to persist those parameters somewhere else like DynamoDB or Redis on Elasticache.

Then, when you need to do your calculations, you can retrieve the past n-1 values and do your calculations.

Comment: I need to access the latest 5 values. But, I am receiving 2 new values every second. Do you thing DynamoDB would be an efficient way?

Comment: I don't see why not. What do you mean by "efficient" anyway?

Comment: writing values which I won't need again after 3 seconds into a database didn't sound like a good solution to me. the database will grow very quickly, and I suspect it will be a slow and costly operation. though, I don't know what other alternatives are possible in AWS

Comment: @mustafa My point is that you persist it somewhere outside Lambda. Whether you put it in a DB, or in S3 or in anything else it up to you. Just don't keep it in Lambda.

Comment: If you decide to use DynamoDB, you can specify a TTL for each record so that each record is deleted after that time expires. It's the same with S3.

Comment: if you are loosing the parameters after a few seconds then elasticcache might be a better solution.  Redis on elasticcache can do this sort of thing easily and it is very fast

Comment: @Vorsprung Redis on Elasticache would have been my recommendation if not for DynamoDB introducing TTL support last February.

Comment: Maybe a good idea would be sending data from AWS IoT to Kinesis streams, and then send it to lambda after buffering to the size of the n messages you want.

Comment: @dvd86 That's another possible implementation. I'd think that will be more expensive, don't you think?